# Linux - Is it possible to create a memory filesystem (ramdisk/tmpfs) to buffer/cache data from disk?

Tags: linux, debian, cache, tmpfs

I've got some code that processes a load of data stored on an external HDD. There is about 6.5 GiB of data on the disk, but only a few files are processed rather than the entire contents.

I created a ramdisk using a tmpfs filesystem to store a copy of the disk contents in memory to speed up the processing time required. Every time I reboot my system, I have to copy the contents of the disk back into this ramdisk.

This works ok, because the entire contents can fit into the amount of available memory that I have.

However it may not work later on when I change to a different, larger dataset.

This is quite inefficient, because the amount of data that I actually read is only about 1 GB. (A bit over 10 % in my estimates.)

Is there a way to create a ramdisk in memory which caches data read from this external disk?

I'm sure such a thing must be possible with linux - but I don't know what to search for. Ramdisks are already quite a niche topic.

Btw I'm using Debian Testing, which at the time of writing is the testing branch ahead of Debian 10.

Edit: I do not write back to this disk, if it makes any difference.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425224/how-to-give-ram-to-the-filesystem-cache
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62382/does-linux-have-ways-to-cache-io-with-memory

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using an [OverlayFS](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt). An overlay filesystem would allow you to merge your disk mountpoint and your ramdisk mountpoint into one stacked filesystem (the overlay).

OverlayFS operates with copy-on-write, so if your upper layer is an empty ramdisk at boot time, data will only be written to the ramdisk when you open the files with write permissions. In theory, you could `touch` any of the files you wanted copied into RAM up front.

Though, I should add, Linux already has [robust disk caching](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Linux_Page_Cache_Basics). You may want to make sure you're not reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: I've an application with thousands of little files in a folder and it randomly accesses these files. I've enough ram to cache all. But I need it to be persistent. So having a write-though cache would be appreciated. Is there a way to build this with OverlayFS or the native disk caching? copy-on-write isn't ideal here either.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question, but might help with the problem described. You want to

> store a copy of the disk contents in memory to speed up the processing time required.

You don't need to do anything. This happens by default.

Try for yourself:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=1M of=test.bin # create a file of 10 GB random data
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches # drop caches
dd if=test.bin bs=1G count=1 of=/dev/null # read 1 GB of data
dd if=test.bin bs=1G count=1 of=/dev/null # read again
```

The first read of takes a while:

```
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 10,43 s, 103 MB/s
```

After the first read, the data remains in memory. Subsequent reads are much faster:

```
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 0.320478 s, 3.4 GB/s
```

Linux will happily support your endeavors by keeping recently read file-content in memory as long there is enough free memory available.

Comment: I didn't know about this. How does Linux decide how large to make this buffer? Is it dynamic?

Comment: Interesting. I fail to find any concrete information on this. Looking at my systems, I can only see that up to 50 % of total ram is typically used for the cache. I do not know if 50 % is a hard upper limit or not.

Comment: Does that amount show up in things like system monitors / htop ? My system has 24 GiB of ram in it - I've never noticed 12 GiB + typical Chrome usage of ~ few GB being used on my system, so I wonder if this is something that is done in a transparent way so that the user is totally unaware of it.

Comment: Yes, it does. Buffers (data to write) and cache (on-disk data available from RAM) are shown blue in [htop](https://serverfault.com/questions/180711/). You can also look at the column "buff/cache" in the output of `env LC_ALL=C free -h`. Please be aware that buffers and cache do not count towards "used" RAM as it can be flushed to disk (buffers) or discarded (cache). "used" is for application data only – this is why the amount of cached data typically is not visible. Also, you cannot really control which data is cached and which is not.

Comment: Strange, I guess I never read that much data from my disk on a day-to-day basis then, because I can't say I've ever noticed.